# Using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am experiencing this problem

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

when invoking a method through reflection

```
 method.invoke(null, input.get(i), result.get(i));
```

Comment: Is the method static? Can you give the signature of the methody you're trying to call?

Answer (score 1):

The method you invoked has thrown an `Exception`:

From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...))

> InvocationTargetException - **if the underlying method throws an**
>   **exception**.

An `InvocationTargetException` is (from [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html))

> ... a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.

It is possible to retrieve the original exception calling the method `getCause` on `InvocationTargetException`

Here is an example

```
try {
    method.invoke(null, input.get(i), result.get(i));
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    Throwable originalException = e.getCause();

    // Print the message of the original exception
    System.out.println(originalException.getMessage()); 
    // ... or do what you like
}
```